# Spring Boot-Unable to connect to JSP in spring boot maven project error (type=Not Found, status=404) is thrown

Tags: spring-boot

I created simple spring boot project to show a jsp output,but error is displayed inspite of following below steps how do i overcome this issue

**ERROR is:**

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
/WEB-INF/jsp/products.jsp
```

**Dependencies added are:**

```
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>   
    </dependency>
```

**I have all my controllers under same folder**

**Controller Code**
    package CRUDRdsapp.CRUDRdsapp;

```
import java.util.Map;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
public class ProductController {



      @RequestMapping("/welcome")
    public String welcome(){
        return "products";
    }

}
```

**properties added to application properties file are:**

```
    spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
    spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

**I placed jsp in webapp/WEB-INF/jsp folder:**
   [prpject folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pel4d.png)